# What is the VSTS alternative for the "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl" classes?

Tags: c#, git, tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

We currently have this C# based program (from VS2010) which programmatically downloads "patch" folders w/ file contents from a TFS Code repository and saves the folders/files to a different location on the network. This tool is also configured to create special emails for maintenance activities.

Recently, we have been migrating our code to a new Git-based VSTS repository as the old TFS repository is being decommissioned. Now, we need to figure out how to get the tool to pull the patch folders from the Git-based VSTS repository instead.

Since the auto-deploy and auto-release functionality in VSTS has not yet been completed, the team still needs this tool to be functional until then. Not sure which package/API/etc I should approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you using Git with Azure DevOps you can use the Azure DevOps [.Net client libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/dotnet-client-libraries).

In the above NuGet packages you can communicate with Git with `GitHttpClient` class.

For example:

```
VssConnection connecttion new VssConnection(new Uri("url"), new VssCredentials());
var gitClient = connection.GetClient<GitHttpClient>();
vat file = gitClient.GetItemAsync();
```

The `GetItemAsync` method let you download files contents from Git repository.

More info and examples you can find [here](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-dotnet-samples).